# How do I use the scipy cdist function on a really big numpy array without getting memory errors?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, jupyter-notebook

I’m trying to find the gravitational potential at every point in a really big 3D grid using numpy arrays. Unfortunately, my 3D grid is so big that I keep running into memory problems and can’t figure out how to do this.

My 3D grid has shape (401,401,401);  the x,y and z axes each extend between -200 and +200.
At each point in the grid I have a mass value. My aim is to compute the gravitational potential at each point. The equation for gravitational potential I am using is:

[image]

Hence to find the gravitational potential at all points in the grid, for each point p in my grid, I must first find the pairwise distance between point p and every other point in the grid. I can then multiply through by the relevant masses and sum over the fraction. Finding the pairwise distances for so many points is where I am having difficulty.

I tried using the scipy distance.cdist function to find the pairwise distances between all the points in my big grid. It works for a much smaller grid: I could find the relevant distances, multiply through by the masses, and sum over each row to get the relevant sum at each point. However, the distance.cdist function doesn’t work with such a big grid; I just get memory errors or the kernel in Jupyter notebook dies because the output array is so big. I’ve also tried dividing up my grid into smaller sub-grids, doing the computation for all the sub-grids and then putting them together. This doesn’t work either: I have to divide the big grid into so many smaller sections that it would take far too long to compute it for all these smaller sections. I’ve also tried using for loops. This also doesn’t work as it would take far too long.

Is there any method I can use to find the sum over all these pairwise distances without running into memory issues?

Thank you!

Comment: You'd need about 17 petabytes of RAM to store such an array.
You need to find another way to achieve what you're trying to do because it's not possible the way you're currently going at it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the pairwise distances? finding all of them at once is not doable due to size.

Comment: @Ehsan I’m trying to compute the gravitational potential at each point on a (401,401,401) grid (I flattened it to get the position array). To do this, for each point p on the grid, I must find the sum of all the pairwise distances between point p and every other point on the grid.  Using scipy cdist and then summing over each row in the output array worked really well on a smaller grid. Is there a different way to compute this sum on the bigger grid?

Comment: @Hillary I think you should edit your question and add these information.

Comment: For the question, I wonder if there is a way to calculate the GP in lazy evaluation style rather then doing all points at once. Do you think you can compute GPs for each point, one by one?

Comment: I think you can divide your grid into smaller sub-grids and do the evaluation and add them up.

Comment: Is it a squared sum? Do you really need all distances (The gravitation influence of points with same mass at high distances may be neglect able, compared to nearer ones). Please specify your real problem.

Comment: @BedirYilmaz I tried using a for loop to calculate the GP at every point. Unfortunately, this doesn’t work either, it takes impossibly long. And thanks for the tip, just edited the question

Comment: @max9111 No, it’s not a square sum. Edited the question to make it more specific. I really want all the distances in this big grid, or at least in a (201,201,201) size grid, which I can’t  figure out either. The bigger grid seems to improve the accuracy of the potential drastically

Comment: @Ehsan Thanks for the advice. Just tried dividing up my grid into smaller sub grids. I found that I had to divide the grid into so many smaller sub grids that it would just take far too long to compute

Comment: @Hillary What if you could compute the potential with respect to distances in each dimension, one by one?

Comment: You can for example write simple loops using Numba and parallelize them (approx. two orders of magnitudes faster than a cdist approach and no memory overhead at all). But this is still far to slow for your problem (400x400x400). A usable approach would be two resample the grid eg. center of mass and sum of mass in every 10x10x10 subgrid. Than calculate the exact potential with near points and use the resampled grid to get the approx. influence of the other particles.